# ZSH + Prezto: CD Tab Completion Issue

Tags: zsh, cd, tab-completion, prezto

I've been thinking about switching over to zsh and prezto for some time now, but there are some nuisances that I'd like to solve first.

Biggest of these is the fact that it seems like the tab completion for 'cd' is messed up somehow. For instance, I've a directory called "git" in my home directory for my git projects and I frequently want to move to it from the home directory, that is, I write this:

```
~ >>> cd g[TAB]
~ >>> cd git
```

Since "git" is the only folder starting with a "g" I obviously expect that to be the result of the tab completion. However, with ZSH and prezto, it instead completes it like this:

```
~ >>> cd g[TAB]
~ >>> cd gnats
```

Using tab again will also try to complete a subfolder to "gnats", neither of which exists!

So far I've at figured out that this is most likely caused by prezto, since disabling it reverts back to the expected behavior.

Any ideas what configuration I have to add to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the shell option `CDABLE_VARS`. You can check if it is set with `setopt | grep cdablevars`. As it is not a default setting you can either find where it is set within *prezto* or explicitly unset it with `setopt nocdablevars` after *prezto* is sourced.

#### Explanation:

If `CDABLE_VARS` is set, *zsh* handles arguments to `cd` that are not directories and do not begin with `/` as if they begin with `~`. This extends to the autocompletion for `cd`.

If a directory name starts with `~` (as is implied by `CDABLE_VARS`), *zsh* checks if the element up to the first `/` can be subsituted in a few different ways. In your case, `~gnats` is interpreted as *static named directory*, which may defined by the following means:

1. automatically for home directories: `~someone` is the home directory of the user *someone*.
2. by setting a shell parameter to a string value which begins with `/`:

   ```
   % SOMEWHERE=/some/directory
   % print ~SOMEWHERE
   /some/directory
   ```
3. by using `hash -d`: `hash -d SOMEWHERE=/some/directory`

I would guess that in this case it is the home directory of the user *gnats*. Which - as far as I can tell - seems to be created by default on at least Debian and Ubuntu.